# Exposed select filter type with content type

Tags: views

In my newly installed Drupal 8 project i have created a content type named *"Hardware Type"* (with several fields, like *name*, *usage*, *requirements* ), for which I have added a bunch of items, and another content type called *"Hardware"*, with several fields (including *"Hardware Type"*, taken from my previously created content type).

Now, I have a view for *"Hardware"*, where I use an exposed filter, with different fields for *"Hardware Type"*, *"Price"*, *"Manufacturer"*.

Currently, the *"Hardware Type"* is a a simple `input[type="text"]`, where I can add IDs from *"Hardware Type"* and filter the list. What I want is this input to be a `select` element with a list of *"Hardware Type"* elements.

Is this possible with what Drupal 8 provides or do I have to create a module? I installed the alpha version of [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) and I making a mess with *Reference Views* but it looks like I need some basic step stones to figure out this apparently simple feature integration

Comment: By its nature, hardware type would better fit a taxonomy term than a content type. And if I recall correctly, taxonomies can be referenced with a select element when used in an exposed filter.

Comment: Just checked, and taxonomies can make use of a dropdown (select) element in exposed filters.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that _Hardware Type_ has several fields (not just the name). Maybe I could create a taxonomy from _Hardware Type_._name_ or something like this

Comment: You can add fields to taxonomy terms too :)